# How can I fix the 'TransportBindingElement' error when consuming a web service in .NET Core with default binding?

Tags: web-services, .net-core, soap

I am tring to consume a web service in my dotnet core7 project.
I don't have access to the service itself.
When I am trying to call a service method it returns that error:

The CustomBinding on the ServiceEndpoint with contract 'IMyService' lacks a TransportBindingElement.
Every binding must have at least one binding element that derives from TransportBindingElement.'

While it uses default binding in reference.

How can I fix it.

I tried overrite the client configuration. but it also didn't work.
private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(TimeSpan timeout)
{
var httpsBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
httpsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
httpsBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;

```
        var integerMaxValue = int.MaxValue;
        httpsBinding.MaxBufferSize = integerMaxValue;
        httpsBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = integerMaxValue;
        httpsBinding.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
        httpsBinding.AllowCookies = true;

        httpsBinding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
        httpsBinding.SendTimeout = timeout;
        httpsBinding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
        httpsBinding.CloseTimeout = timeout;

        return httpsBinding;
    }
```

And in creating client:
_RedemptionServiceClient = new RedemptionLiteIntegrationServiceClient("https://78.93.37.230:9799/RedemptionLiteIntegrationServiceBasicHttpEndPoint", new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0),"","");

Comment: Could you check what is your System.ServiceModel.Primitives version? Try 4.10.2 and you should be good to go.

Comment: could u solve it?